# Populate html table or list with dynamic data from backend

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, angular, typescript

I have a C# api endpoint that returns a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`.

The problem here is this list is dynamic, so I cannot say what the elements could be so I could populate an html list (say with angular) with it, i.e.

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of dataList">
<li><span>{{data.propertyName}}<span/> -- <span>{{data.propertyValue}}<span/><li>
<ul>
```

Another data from the endpoint could have more data and different list properties, so instead of `propertyName` and `propertyValue` it could be `employeeID`, `employeeName`, `dateOfBirth` etc.

How do I populate the list with only one list markup and api endpoint?

Comment: Why reactjs and angular tags?

Comment: because a lot of devs use these frameworks/libraries to get data from backend and they could have faced the blocker before

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your data set? Like what the network response for this request even look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, then in Angular you'll have the property:

```
dataList: object[]; // data model is unknown
```

In that case you can:

```
keys: string[];
...
this.keys = Object.keys(dataList[0]); // once data is retrieved you can extract its model
```

And in your HTML you can for example:

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of dataList">
    <li *ngFor="let prop of keys">
        <span>{{ prop }}: {{ data[prop] }} | <span/>
    <li>
<ul>
```